# Text drag-n-drop is broken

Tags: bug, editor

Usually when writing a text I can drag-n-drop selected text inside of the field or to the other field. But in case of question field I can't:

> [image: screenvideo from question (broken)]

Note that it works fine with title:

> [image: screenvideo from title (working)]

Comment: I can reproduce.  Answers are affected the same way.

Comment: In [SE's wmd.js](https://dev.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.js), on line 5276, the `drop` handler which is looking for droped files unconditionally does a `return false;`. Doing that causes [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to be called, which prevents the browser from performing the default action of moving the text.

Comment: Huh. I've never been able to use Drag-and-drop here. Thought it was a site restriction...