# Drag and drop to upload image stopped working in SO

Tags: bug, image-upload

Can other people reproduce / confirm this? Try dragging the image in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728936/how-does-xtheta-in-cost-function-from) e.g., into an image upload to the answer box below.

It used to respond with a box to accept the drag & drop operation, now it just stays there not responding.

I have reproduced this in both Firefox and Chrome (linux).

---

**UPDATE**: Sorry, I should have included this to begin with. I have tried this in:

- Firefox 72.0.1 (64-bit), and
- Google Chrome v79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Running on Linux Mint 19.1 (Cinnamon).

---

<sub>PS. Before anyone is inevitably tempted to make [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361361/simpler-image-upload#comment544355_361361) knee-jerk, my main use for this functionality is to upload latex math with minimal effort.</sub>

Comment: Something similar got reported but only for text within the editor: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392820/text-drag-n-drop-is-broken

Comment: I didn't knew I could do that..

Comment: I can't reproduce this; that is, I can drag an image into the answer box, and the moment I let go of the mouse button the imgur *add picture* drawer opens with the dropped image. Firefox 72 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Also can't reproduce. Firefox 72 on Windows 10. Tried it on MetaSO and main SO.

Comment: I _can_ reproduce it (Chrome 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10).

Comment: As a workaround you can copy the image and then paste it in the answer box.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Edge Chromium Version 81.0.381.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: *Cannot* reproduce on Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10... @Ivar, what were your repro steps? I did the same thing as [Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392881/drag-and-drop-to-upload-image-stopped-working-in-so#comment748925_392881).

Comment: Okay, I *can* repro by dragging an image from the browser to the browser, but not Windows Explorer to the browser.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've tried it multiple ways without success. But one way was as mentioned in the question: For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728936/how-does-xtheta-in-cost-function-from) drag the image in that question to the answer box.

Comment: @Ivar Yeah, for me, it's going from browser to browser that's not working. From Explorer to browser works fine. And, as you mentioned, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V works too.

Comment: @HereticMonkey OK, Firefox 72 on Windows 10 - also cannot drag and drop from the browser (same one) to the answer field. But...should we be able to? The whole "drag from browser" thing pretty much never works with anything, from my experience. Unless it's *from* one web app *to the same* web app. Even then, that has to be explicitly implemented - most of the times it isn't.

Comment: @VLAZ  I'm with you, but the OP says it used to work. And it seems like it's in the same app (SO). Now that has to talk to Imgur, but I was under the impression that the upload thing was a SO-developed skin for imgur's API. Could be very wrong though.

Comment: @VLAZ my particular use-case was generating latex equation images easily and instantly in a desktop app (anki, to be exact) with minimal overhead needed, and drag&drop them directly to SO. This also means there was no weblink to copy as a workaround. Anything else I do takes at least 10-30 seconds more than this workflow per equation needed.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou just to clarify - you create an image in a desktop app of some description and then you drag and drop it but how? Are you dragging it *from* that application's interface? Dragging the application Save it to disk and dragging it from a file system explorer? I that *might* be related to the application, although if you've not changed anything with it (like updating) nor anything with your system and it used to work before but not now, then it certainly suggests a problem on here. I've only tried dragging a file from Windows Explorer and worked but that might not mean much.

Comment: @VLAZ W.r.t. the bug, the app is a red herring of course, because the functionality also broke for internal images (see question). But, yes, anki is a flashcard program, and the generated flashcards are effectively html. It handles latexmath-to-image conversion seamlessly and embeds the image in the generated html card dynamically, which can then be drag&dropped. Obviously describing the infrastructure involved like this probably makes it sound _more_ complicated, but the end result is that I can type [$] \int_a^b dx [/$] and as soon as I've finished typing there's an image I can drag.

Comment: @VLAZ obviously all that is academic. The bottom line is that there's a bug. (the worst kind: reproducible by some and not by others).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yeah. I'm trying to figure out if it can be more easily reproducible.

Comment: @VLAZ go to the link in my question. In the answer box, click the "Image" button. Now try to drag&drop the latex image in the question, down into the answer box. If the answer box responds by creating a drag&drop "landing" area, then you are not seeing the bug. If the answer box remains the same and drag&dropping has no effect, you have reproduced the bug. :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou OK, I apologise - *now* I got what you mean. Wouldn't you know - were I to follow the reproduction steps *correctly*, I am able to reproduce the bug. Went to the question, dragged the image from the question to the answer box and nothing happens. Sorry for being bad at this...

Comment: @VLAZ hahah, no worries, hopefully the comments above will help others to reproduce too.